# some issues in moto g 2nd generation after lollipop version

Tags: updates, motorola-moto-g

After updating my Moto G 2014 to Lollipop I have started experiencing some issues as I don't know how to get it fixed. So the problems are:

- Autorotate option isn't showing,
- If I tried pressing and holding the power button, I can only see the power off option, I can't find the silent option.
- While on the call, previously I have the ability to write a number on the dialpad which I can correct if I tap in the wrong number but now I can't find the backspace button to correct that !

Please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

1. Settings -> Accessibility -> Auto Rotate.
2. Silent mode is now changed to Priority mode. Press the volume down button and you will find the priority mode
3. No easy solution for this. While on call press back button until you reach the homescreen. Now go back again to call screen from notification bar. Now the typed number will be gone